# Maven .jar file with dependencies won't work on any other device besides the device it was made on

Tags: java, maven, itext, apache-poi, javax.imageio

It is really weird,
I'm making a flyermaker for my company, they need a mass scale of flyers. I am using the buildin ImageIO from java, also the iTextpdf (newest version) with the apache POI. I will put my pom.xml below.

On both a windows 8 and windows 10 the application won't work. I will provide all the code of my program below. As soon as i press make flyers there is nothing happening in the background. I don't get why.

I am building my project with the following mvn statement:
clean compile assembly:single

I am using Netbeans 11.3 and Java 8

POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.houseoftyping</groupId>
    <artifactId>FlyerMaker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.houseoftyping.flyermaker.main.Start</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Start.java (main class) I have removed all the variables, JButton's JPanes etc. to save characters. These are autogenerated so nothing is wrong with them.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.houseoftyping.flyermaker.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.IIOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

/**
 *
 * @author Lorenzo
 */
public class Start extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form selectExcel
     */
    public Start() {
        initComponents();
    }                     

    private void selectExcelFileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Kies een excel bestand");
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File currentFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            excelFileLocation.setText(String.valueOf(currentFile));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Selection.... try again");
        }
    }                                               

    private void selectFolderActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose a folder");
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File currentFolder = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            folderLocation.setText(String.valueOf(currentFolder));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Selection.... try again");
        }
    }                                            

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if (excelFileLocation.getText() == "") {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "U heeft geen excel bestand gekozen, kies eerst een excel bestand.", "Geen excel bestand gekozen.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else if (folderLocation.getText() == "") {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "U heeft geen eindmap gekozen voor de gemaakte flyers, kies eerst een eindmap.", "Geen map gekozen.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else if (logoFolderLocation.getText() == "") {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "U heeft map gekozen met de schoollogo's, kies eerst een map.", "Geen map gekozen.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            try {
                jButton1.setBackground(Color.red);
                jButton1.setEnabled(false);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "Flyers worden gemaakt!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                Excel excel = new Excel();
                if (!excel.readExcel(new File(excelFileLocation.getText()), new File(this.folderLocation.getText()), new File(logoFolderLocation.getText()))) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Het gekozen excel bestand verdoet niet aan de eisen. Voor de juiste eisen tik op Help.", "Excel bestand voldoet niet aan eisen.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    resetButton(jButton1);
                }
            } catch (IIOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Het logo wat in het excel bestand staat kan niet worden gevonden. Kijk of de juiste naam in het excel bestand staat en de juiste type.", "Fout bij plaatsen van logo", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                resetButton(jButton1);
            } catch (InvalidFormatException ex) {
                resetButton(jButton1);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                resetButton(jButton1);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alle flyers zijn succesvol gemaakt!", "Succes!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                resetButton(jButton1);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Het excel bestand wat u wilt gebruiken kan niet worden gevonden, of staat nog open in een ander venster.", "Fout bij uitlezen van Excel bestand", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                resetButton(jButton1);
            }
        }
    }                                        

    private void selectFolder2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose a folder");
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File currentFolder = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            logoFolderLocation.setText(String.valueOf(currentFolder));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Selection.... try again");
        }
    }                                             

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Start.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Start.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Start.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Start.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Start().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void resetButton(JButton button) {
        button.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(138, 204, 234));
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }        
}
```

Excel.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.houseoftyping.flyermaker.main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

/**
 *
 * @author Lorenzo
 */
public class Excel {

    File outputFolder;
    File logoFolder;

    public Boolean readExcel(File excelFile, File output, File logoLocation) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, ParseException {
        this.outputFolder = output;
        this.logoFolder = logoLocation;
        // Retrieving the number of sheets in the Workbook
        try ( // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
                Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(excelFile)) {
            // Retrieving the number of sheets in the Workbook
            System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");
            // 2. Or you can use a for-each loop
            for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
                if (sheet.getSheetName().equals("secundair flyer")) {
                    System.out.println("Secundair flyer geselecteerd");
                    createFlyersFromExcel(sheet);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void createFlyersFromExcel(Sheet sheet) throws IOException, ParseException {
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
        boolean firstRow = false;
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            if (firstRow == false) {
                int count = 0;
                firstRow = true;
            } else {
                if (!dataFormatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0)).equals("0")) {
                    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Cell cell : row) {
                        cell.setCellFormula(null);
                        String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                        if (!cellValue.equals("0")) {
                            values.add(cellValue);
                        } else {
                            values.add(null);
                        }
                    }
                    if (values.get(1) == null) {
                    } else {
                        School s = new School(values, logoFolder);
                        if (s.getLocationLogo() != null) {
                            Flyer flyer = new Flyer(s, outputFolder);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Flyer.java:
This is where the flyer is made. Please ignore the hardcoded text, that is a problem for later to solve.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.houseoftyping.flyermaker.main;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @author Lorenzo
 */
public class Flyer {

    private BufferedImage page1;
    private BufferedImage page2;
    private School s;

    public Flyer(School school, File outputFolder) throws IOException {
        s = school;
        if (school.getFlyerType() == null) {

        } else {
            setCorrectPagesByType();
            fillFlyer();
            finishFlyer(outputFolder);
        }
    }

    private void setCorrectPagesByType() throws IOException {
        try {
            page2 = ImageIO.read(new File("C://Users/Lorenzo/Desktop/house-of-typing-inside.jpg"));
            if (s.getFlyerType().equals("1")) {
                page1 = ImageIO.read(new File("C://Users/Lorenzo/Desktop/house-of-typing-outside-1.jpg"));
            } else if (s.getFlyerType().equals("2")) {
                page1 = ImageIO.read(new File("C://Users/Lorenzo/Desktop/house-of-typing-outside-2.jpg"));
            } else if (s.getFlyerType().equals("3")) {
                page1 = ImageIO.read(new File("C://Users/Lorenzo/Desktop/house-of-typing-outside-3.jpg"));
            } else {
                page1 = ImageIO.read(new File("C://Users/Lorenzo/Desktop/house-of-typing-outside-4.jpg"));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void fillFlyer() throws IOException {
        handleSchool();
        handleType();
    }

    private void handleSchool() throws IOException {
        //Course code (only at design 1)
        if (s.getFlyerType().equals("1")) {
            //renders text
        } else if (s.getFlyerType().equals("2")) {
            //renders text
        } else if (s.getFlyerType().equals("3")) {
            //renders text
        } else {
            //renders text
        }
        //renders text

        if (s.getFlyerType().equals("2")) {
            //renders text
        }
        if (s.getFlyerType().equals("1") || s.getFlyerType().equals("2")) {
            //renders text
        } else if (s.getFlyerType().equals("3")) {
            //renders text
        } else {
            //renders text
        }
    }

    private void handleType() {
        if (s.getFlyerType().equals("1")) {
            //renders text

        } else if (s.getFlyerType().equals("2")) {
            //renders text

        } else if (s.getFlyerType().equals("3")) {
            //renders text

        } else if (s.getFlyerType().equals("4")) {
            //renders text
        }
    }

    public void renderText(int page, String text, String font, int fontSize, Color color, int width, int height) {
        final Graphics2D g;
        if (page == 1) {
            g = (Graphics2D) page1.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(page1, 0, 0, null);
        } else {
            g = (Graphics2D) page2.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(page2, 0, 0, null);
        }
        g.setFont(new Font(font, Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
        g.setColor(color);
        for (String txt : text.split("\n")) {
            g.drawString(txt, width, height += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
        }
        g.dispose();
    }

    public void renderImage(int page, File image, int width, int height, double scale, boolean mainLogo) throws IOException {
        final Graphics2D g;
        if (page == 1) {
            g = (Graphics2D) page1.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(page1, 0, 0, null);
        } else {
            g = (Graphics2D) page2.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(page2, 0, 0, null);
        }
        BufferedImage biImage = ImageIO.read(image);
        final AlphaComposite alphaChannel = AlphaComposite.getInstance(3, 1.0f);
        g.setComposite(alphaChannel);
            if (mainLogo) {
                while (biImage.getHeight() < 250) {
                    biImage = resize(biImage.getWidth() * 2, biImage.getHeight() * 2, biImage);
                }
                while (biImage.getHeight() > 500) {
                    biImage = resize(biImage.getWidth() / 1.2, biImage.getHeight() / 1.2, biImage);
                }
            } else {
                while (biImage.getHeight() < 150) {
                    biImage = resize(biImage.getWidth() * 2, biImage.getHeight() * 2, biImage);
                }
                while (biImage.getHeight() > 300) {
                    biImage = resize(biImage.getWidth() / 1.2, biImage.getHeight() / 1.2, biImage);
                }
            }
        g.drawImage(biImage, width, height, null);
        g.dispose();
    }

    public static BufferedImage resize(double targetWidth, double targetHeight,
            BufferedImage src) {
        double scaleW = (double) targetWidth / (double) src.getWidth();
        double scaleH = (double) targetHeight / (double) src.getHeight();

        double scale = scaleW < scaleH ? scaleW : scaleH;

        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage((int) (src.getWidth() * scale),
                (int) (src.getHeight() * scale), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g2d = result.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(src, 0, 0, result.getWidth(), result.getHeight(), null);
        g2d.dispose();

        return result;
    }

    public void renderTiltedText(int page, String text, String font, int fontSize, Color color, int width, int height, double angle) {
        final Graphics2D g;
        if (page == 1) {
            g = (Graphics2D) page1.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(page1, 0, 0, null);
        } else {
            g = (Graphics2D) page2.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(page2, 0, 0, null);
        }
        g.setFont(new Font(font, Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
        g.setColor(color);

        g.translate((float) 0, (float) 0);
        g.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));

        for (String txt : text.split("\n")) {
            g.drawString(txt, width, height += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
        }

        g.rotate(-Math.toRadians(angle));
        g.translate(-(float) 0, -(float) 0);

        g.dispose();
    }

    public ArrayList<BufferedImage> rotateFlyer() {
        ArrayList<BufferedImage> pages = new ArrayList<>();
        pages.add(page1);
        pages.add(page2);
        ArrayList<BufferedImage> rotatedPages = new ArrayList<>();

        for (BufferedImage image : pages) {
            final double rads = Math.toRadians(90);
            final double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(rads));
            final double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(rads));
            final int w = (int) Math.floor(image.getWidth() * cos + image.getHeight() * sin);
            final int h = (int) Math.floor(image.getHeight() * cos + image.getWidth() * sin);
            final BufferedImage rotatedImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, image.getType());
            final AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
            at.rotate(rads, 0, 0);
            at.translate(-image.getWidth() / 2, -image.getHeight() / 2);
            final AffineTransformOp rotateOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
            rotateOp.filter(image, rotatedImage);
            rotatedPages.add(rotatedImage);
        }
        return rotatedPages;
    }

    public void finishFlyer(File outputFile) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<BufferedImage> pages = rotateFlyer();
        File firstPage = new File(outputFile + "\\" + s.getSchoolName() + "-" + 1 + ".jpg");
        ImageIO.write(pages.get(0), "png", firstPage);
        File secondPage = new File(outputFile + "\\" + s.getSchoolName() + "-" + 2 + ".jpg");
        ImageIO.write(pages.get(1), "png", secondPage);
        try {
            PDF pdf = new PDF(firstPage, secondPage, outputFile, s.getSchoolName());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Flyer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Flyer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        firstPage.delete();
        secondPage.delete();
        System.out.println("finished flyer of " + s.getSchoolName());
    }
}
```

PDF.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.houseoftyping.flyermaker.main;

import com.itextpdf.text.BadElementException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Lorenzo
 */
public class PDF {

    public PDF(File image1, File image2, File root, String schoolName) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException, BadElementException, IOException {
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        files.add(image1);
        files.add(image2);
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(new File(root, schoolName + ".pdf")));
        document.open();
        for (File f : files) {
            document.newPage();
            Image image;
            image = Image.getInstance(f.getAbsolutePath());
            image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
            image.setBorderWidth(0);
            image.scaleAbsoluteHeight(PageSize.A4.getHeight());
            image.scaleAbsoluteWidth(PageSize.A4.getWidth());
            document.add(image);
        }
        document.close();
    }
}
```

School.java is basicly only setters for the values.

Comment: it'll work just fine, but on the other machine, it'll still need those libraries

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the maven-assmebly plugin section as below to bind to the packaging phase.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
      <archive>
          <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.houseoftyping.flyermaker.main.Start</mainClass>
          </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id> 
      <phase>package</phase> 
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Also, it is always a good idea to review the generated jar with jar tf command or a simple unzip utility to confirm that it is built with all dependency and correct entry in the Manifest file.

Comment: Now i found the problem, i have images saved in a other package, but they are not with the .jar file. How can i fix this? Also, there are still other dependencies with the jar like json-simple, how can i remove this from the package?